# Rails has_many :through dependent :destroy behaving very oddly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_many :tasks_users, :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => {:is_owner => true}
  has_many :tasks, :through => :tasks_users, :source => :task
```

Task:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  include RankedModel
  ranks :sort_order

  acts_as_taggable

  has_many :tasks_users  
  has_many :users, :through => :tasks_users
```

TasksUser:

```
class TasksUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :is_owner
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :task

    validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => [:user_id, :task_id]
end
```

They key here is dependent destroy.

Whenever I try to destroy my user, which should destroy the join model, I end up getting this odd sql error:

```
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "taggings".* FROM "taggings" WHERE "taggings"."tagger_id" = 17 AND "taggings"."tagger_type" = 'User'
  TasksUser Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "tasks_users".* FROM "tasks_users" WHERE "tasks_users"."user_id" = 17 AND "tasks_users"."is_owner" = 't'
Could not log "sql.active_record" event. NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
**SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: tasks_users.: DELETE FROM "tasks_users" WHERE "tasks_users"."" = ?**
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: tasks_users.: DELETE FROM "tasks_users" WHERE "tasks_users"."" = ?
from /home/steveq/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails32/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

The line with the double asterisk is the line in question - it appears to be searching for a record in "tasks_users"."".

If all I do is change :conditions => {:is_owner => false}, the sql executes without a problem:

```
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "taggings".* FROM "taggings" WHERE "taggings"."tagger_id" = 17 AND "taggings"."tagger_type" = 'User'
  TasksUser Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "tasks_users".* FROM "tasks_users" WHERE "tasks_users"."user_id" = 17 AND "tasks_users"."is_owner" = 'f'
  List Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "lists".* FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."owner_id" = 17
  Relationship Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "relationships".* FROM "relationships" WHERE "relationships"."user_id" = 17
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["id", 17]]
   (299.4ms)  commit transaction
```

Any ideas about what's happening here, and why having the condition of is_owner change from true to false allows the query and delete statement to execute?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ugh - Hopefully I can save someone else from banging their heads against this wall for an hour.

Problem was how I specified the :conditions.

It needed to be put in double quotes:

```
  has_many :tasks_users, :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => "is_owner = 'true'"
```

That was it.